# Repeat each element in an iterable (which can be infinite) using itertools only

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there a simpler expression for the following, which would use `itertools` and not require defining a function?

It must support any iterable, including infinite sequences from generators.

I looked through the recipes in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html and did not find anything obvious.

```
def repeat_each(iterable, n):
    """Repeat each element in iterable n times"""
    it = iter(iterable)
    for element in it:
      for _ in range(n):
        yield element

a = itertools.cycle('abcd')
b = repeat_each(a, 4)
print(''.join(itertools.islice(b, 30)))
# Output: 'aaaabbbbccccddddaaaabbbbccccdd'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it covers all the cases you have in mind, but you could use `tee` (replicating the iterater `n` times) and then `zip` and `chain` it:

```
from itertools import tee, chain, cycle, islice

a = cycle('abcd')
b = chain.from_iterable(zip(*tee(a, 4)))
print(''.join(islice(b, 30)))
```

Result:

```
aaaabbbbccccddddaaaabbbbccccdd
```